# Linear diophantine equation $97y-299x=10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Here is my equation:
$$97y-299x=10$$
I tried to solve like this:
$$-299 =-3\cdot97-8$$
$$97=-12\cdot-8+1$$
$$-8=-8\cdot1+0$$
I'm not sure if I am correct or can I ignore the negative signs?

Comment: You can ignore the minus sign of $299$ and obtain a solution $(x_0,y_0)$  of $97y+299x=10$, then $(-x_0,y_0)$ will be a solution of $97y-299x=10$

Comment: It is very hard to comment here. There are infinitely many solutions. You seem to have pulled some numbers out of a hat and have plugged them in. I'm uncertain if you are severely out of your depth or if you've only casually glanced at this problem before. Either way, I do not feel like I have a good enough grasp of your level of understanding to provide a comprehensible answer. I can say that this is a "linear diophantine equation in 2 variables" and that google will lead to you to treatises on the subject (even on MSE). The phrase "linear congruence" might also be helpful.

Comment: @mixedmath I am sorry but I don't think i can give you the whole question because it is from my puzzle based learning question.

Comment: What kind of solutions do you want? The value of one value given the other? Integer pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the signs.

$97 = 12\cdot8 + 1$ and $299 - 3\cdot97 = 8$ implies

$97 = 12\cdot(299 - 3\cdot97) + 1$ implies

$-12\cdot299+36\cdot97 + 97 = 1$ implies

$-12\cdot299+37\cdot97 = 1$

Multiply both sides by 10 and you get

$-120(299)+370(97) = 10$

$370(97)-120(299) = 10$

The general solution would be

$(x,y) = (120 + 97t, 370+299t)$